# rails capistrano deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have installed capistrano with `gem capistrano`

And in my application directory i installed `cap install`

This command includes `deploy/production.rb` and `deploy/staging.rb` and in `config/deploy.rb`

my `production.rb` file has following

```
set :stage, :production
role :all, %w{seting@mydomain.com}
server 'sub.mydomain.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true, :port => 1754, :keys => %w(/home/seting/.ssh/id_rsa) }
```

And this is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, 'admin'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/myadmin.git'
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

And finally when i run `cap production deploy`

Getting errors as

```
cap aborted!
seting
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:156:in `ssh'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:68:in `upload!'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.0.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Edit - 1**

In addition i didn't do any special installations in my server to run rails application. I have decided to move my file to server first. Is it right way?

Comment: Have you run `cap production deploy:setup`?  Does that work or give you the same error?

Comment: getting error as `Don't know how to build task 'deploy:setup'`

Comment: Whether i have to configure any thing else in my server or in git

Answer (score 12):

You should set role name deploy instead of seting, or other way.

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, '/srv/www/server.com/'
role :all, %w{deploy@server.com}
server 'server.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :production)
```

Here is the [guide](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/)

And you probably want to run

```
cap production deploy:check
```

to check your config.

Also there is no deploy:setup in capistrano 3.0

Comment: An excellent point. I missed that he was using 3.0.  Great catch.

Comment: I tried the above link you given but facing same problem. Can you please help me.

Comment: how is done the setup on server? manually? there is no task to do the mkdir for the required folder structure?